# how to use all mysql query results in php

Tags: php, mysql

i need to get and update all results of the query, i get all the results but it updates only the first result, why? Thanks in advance.

```
$result=mysql_query(" SELECT text FROM sess WHERE dest='$name' AND mitt='$mitt' AND read='0'  ORDER BY idm  ");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         $messages[]=$row[$i];
         $mess= mysql_real_escape_string($row[$i]);
         mysql_query(" UPDATE sess SET read='1' WHERE dest='$name' AND mitt='$mitt' AND text='$mess' ");
         $i++;
        }
```

Comment: **mysql_*** is **deprecated** use MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the first index of your result row.

```
$result=mysql_query(" SELECT text FROM sess WHERE dest='$name' AND mitt='$mitt' AND read='0'  ORDER BY idm  ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     $messages[]=$row[0];
     $mess= mysql_real_escape_string($row[0]);
     mysql_query(" UPDATE sess SET read='1' WHERE dest='$name' AND mitt='$mitt' AND text='$mess' ");
     $i++;
}
```

**Note:** that the functions you are using `mysql_*` are deprecated. There are some alternatives, `mysqli_*` being a direct replacement. Read [more here](http://idiallo.com/blog/2013/04/dealing-with-mysql-once-and-for-all.html)

**Note 2:**
Use the ID of the message to set the message as read. Using the content of the text is inefficient.

```
UPDATE sess SET read='1' WHERE message_id = $messageId
```

Comment: @lbu; What's your opinion? In my mind it seems he want to select some records and finally update `read=1` for each record and get the amount of updated results. Therefore why not just running `UPDATE sess SET read=1 WHERE dest='$name' AND mitt='$mitt' AND read='0'"` and finally get the amount by `mysqli_affected_rows`. Do yo agree?

Comment: Possibly its to set all the messages being displayed as read. The best way to get an answer is to ask the OP

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do

```
UPDATE sess SET read='1' WHERE dest='$name' AND mitt='$mitt' AND read='0' ?
```

Comment: ... and read them after (or before) the update-command. This is more effective than many update-commands.

Comment: Don't know why this is downvoted. Doesn't answer the literal question, but provides a perfectly fine (even better) alternative to the not working code. Could use some more explanation, though.

Answer (score 0):

try that :

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

     mysql_query(" UPDATE sess SET read='1' WHERE dest='$name' AND mitt='$mitt' AND text='".$row['text']."' ");

    }
```

or this:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $id = mysql_real_escape_string($row['id']);
 mysql_query("UPDATE sess SET read='1' WHERE `id` = '$id' ");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id ,text FROM sess WHERE dest='$name' AND mitt='$mitt' AND read='0'  ORDER BY idm  ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $messages[]=$row['text'];
     $id = mysql_real_escape_string($row['id']);
     mysql_query("UPDATE sess SET read='1' WHERE `id` = '$id' ");
     $i++;
}
```

Comment: Assumes there is an `id`, doesn't explain what happens or why it is better.

Comment: @GolezTrol If you read his question he wants to update each record of select result as `read=1` therefore in the while he can update just that specific record by selecting by id

Comment: If there is an id. Where do you get the idea that there is an `id`? Maybe there *should* be..

Comment: It's just recommended it does not mean there is and id; it can be any unique field which might be used as key

Comment: Of course. Sound advice, but it doesn't answer the question, so it should rather be a comment. He already uses a combination of fields that (apparently) is unique. This isn't the problem.

Comment: How can you guarantee that the result of `WHERE dest='$name' AND mitt='$mitt' AND text='$mess'` is making it unique? If it really makes it unique then he does not need to run the query inside the `while` he can just run the `update` query after `while`